# JPA - reset entity property on server restart

Tags: java, eclipselink

is it possible to declare an entity property so that it is reset to some default value, but only if the server hosting the ejb.jar is restarted?

the properties are used to to reflect the state of some connected clients that will be disconnected on restart.

Perhaps i should aprouch this problem with a different solution, but think the question is still valid.

Comment: Usually container (HTTP, EJB) allow you to associate listeners to their lifecycles, so you can implement actions to do when a webapp starts, stops, etc...

Comment: sounds like a way forward. but when i look for documentation i dont find much on container lifecycle, only on ejb/entity.  for example is it possible to anotate methods to hook em to container lifecycle?

Comment: What you do not like of Eugene's solution?

Comment: it would reset the values even when only reploying the .war. However i found out in another question that a singleton ejb could be used with @startup, as it will be constructed on deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with @Singleton and @Startup annotated EJB, tests seem to work

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ClientResetBean {

    // Injected database connection:
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;


    @PostConstruct
    private void resetClientState() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE Client c SET c.online = false");
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you have a hook that is triggered on application start/stop? Like **ServletContextListener**? On stop save the entries(users) interested in into a intermediar DB table and on start just re-connect.